# filter decimal values in angular 2 pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-pipe

I created a pipe which filters numbers, but the same pipe is failing when i am trying to filter decimal values. Can anybody tell me how to do that.
    Below is what I have tried.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterSellerNumber',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterSellerNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, SellerNumber: any): string {
    if (!searchSellerNumber) return items;
    return items.filter(function(item){
      if(item.roleId.includes(SellerNumber)){
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

`items` holds the json data and `SellerNumber` holds user input from a textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails'? Does it throw an error or is the result unexpected? Can you give examples for both items and SellerNumber (concrete values) where it works / doesn't work?

Comment: It says "item.roleId.includes is not a function"

Comment: [{ roleId : "1000.50"},{roleId: "2000.5"}]

Comment: Then roleId is probably not a string. Try converting it: `(item.roleId + '').includes(...`

Comment: sure, let me try.

Comment: Thanks Kim,it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `item.roleId.includes is not a function` tells you, that item.roleId is not a string value. You have to convert it first: `(item.roleId + '').includes(...`